# How to set a DropShadow on UITableView itself

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to set a dropshadow on a `UITableView` which is being added programmatically.

The frame height is being set to a certain percentage of the screen. So I want to set a dropshadow on the tableview itself.

I tried doing the following:

```
tableview_results.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: tableview_results.frame).cgPath
tableview_results.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
tableview_results.layer.opacity = 1
tableview_results.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
tableview_results.layer.shadowRadius = 10
```

However this doesn't seem to do anything.

When I try searching for a solution, I only find stuff regarding how to set a dropshadow on the last cell of the `UITableView`. However this would not work for me since then the shadow will only be displayed when the last cell is displayed.

I need the shadow to be always present on the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shadow path should be set to the `tableview_results.bounds` not `frame`.  The bounds is the rectangle around the table view in the coordinate system of the table view itself, and that's the correct coordinate system in which to specify the shadow path.  Alternatively, you can just not set the shadow path at all and the shadow will draw in the correct place (though perhaps there's a performance benefit to setting the path explicitly if you can do so reliably).

You also need to set the `shadowOpacity` not the `opacity` of the layer, to 1.  And you need to tell the `tableview_results` to not `clipToBounds`.  So something like this:

```
tableview_results.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: tableview_results.bounds).cgPath
tableview_results.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
tableview_results.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
tableview_results.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
tableview_results.layer.shadowRadius = 10
tableview_results.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

And for that last line, if you feel like the code is cleaner by only talking to the layer, you can equivalently use `tableview_results.layer.masksToBounds = NO`.

Note that there is a side effect of turning off clipping:  Now you might see table view cells beyond the bounds of the table view itself!  So there might be better ways to get the shadow effect.  You could, for example, wrap the table view in a simple superview that tightly bounds the tableview, and give the shadow to that superview.  Just a thought.

Comment: Ended up with adding the tableview to a view because the `clipsToBounds` caused some strange behaviour like you predicted. Would you also possibly  know how I could apply the shadow to only show on the bottom of the `UIView`?

Comment: I added the tableView to a container UIView and set a shadow in the container. Worked great but now the tableView cells do not respond to touch events. Any ideas?